# What does "not run" mean in R help pages?

Tags: r

Sometimes on an R help page the phrase "not run" appears in comments. Check out this from the help page for "with()":

```
Examples
require(stats); require(graphics)
#examples from glm:
**## Not run:** 
library(MASS)
with(anorexia, {
    anorex.1 <- glm(Postwt ~ Prewt + Treat + offset(Prewt),
                    family = gaussian)
    summary(anorex.1)
})
## End(**Not run**)
```

What does the "not run" mean in the example code?

Comment: just a related tip. You can run the example code by issuing  "example(glm)".

Comment: That is a good tip. And I'd bet that the vast majority of R users aren't aware of it.

Comment: but note example(fn) will still not example code wrapped in `dontRun`

Comment: except if you set the `run.dontrun` parameter to `TRUE`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

"not run" encloses code that shouldn't be executed in the `example` function (e.g. time-consuming code parts, user-interaction, ...).

see e.g. `?example`:

As detailed in the manual *Writing R Extensions*, the author of
the help page can markup parts of the examples for two exception
rules

- 'dontrun' encloses code that should not be run.
- 'dontshow' encloses code that is invisible on help pages, but will
   be run both by the package checking tools, and the
   'example()' function.  This was previously 'testonly', and
   that form is still accepted.

Comment: ... how did I not know about this function?

Comment: It's not just time-consuming code that typically is put inside of a \dontrun{}.  Code that requires user input needs to be be inside dontrun as well or else it won't pass `R CMD check`

Comment: Or:  code that depends on a package that might not be installed on the user's machine. There are lots and lots and lots of reasons to use \dontrun{}

Comment: @MattParker I know, whattttt

Answer (score 29):

In ["Writing R Extensions"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Documenting-functions) manual, in section about \examples{...} is said that

> You can use \dontrun{} for text that should only be shown, but not run, and \dontshow{} for extra commands for testing that should not be shown to users, but will be run by example()

When you build a package then all code in \dontrun{} closure is visible in help as

```
## Not run:
...
## End(**Not run**)
```

edit: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454211/what-does-not-run-mean-in-r-help-pages/1454340#1454340) was earlier.

Answer (score 17):

This adds `\donttest{}` and is taken (verbatim) from @hadley's [R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/).

> However for the purpose of illustration, it’s often useful to include code that causes an error. **`\dontrun{}`** allows you to include code in the example that is never used. There are two other special commands. **`\dontshow{}`** is run, but not shown in the help page: this can be useful for informal tests. **`\donttest{}`** is run in examples, but not run automatically in R CMD check. This is useful if you have examples that take a long time to run. The options are summarised below.

```
Command      example    help       R CMD check
\dontrun{}                 x
\dontshow{}       x                          x
\donttest{}       x        x
```

Comment: Note that donttest is now tested

Comment: For package submission, do you have to have any additional comments in the .Rd justifying omission of the code block? I had a package fail check because of a \donttest{} example and am wondering if it is a simple as changing it to \dontrun{}. The function is for downloading data from an ftp and the CRAN comment is: "That is not commented on in the .Rd files. Note that example() will run these sections".

Comment: Yes it should be that simple.

Comment: @TylerRinker you mean the function is verified as working, or the code with in @donttest{ } is now run by CRAN when doing checks?

Comment: Yes heres a quote from Hadley 's book: "For the purpose of illustration, it’s often useful to include code that causes an error. \dontrun{} allows you to include code in the example that is not run. (You used to be able to use \donttest{} for a similar purpose, but it’s no longer recommended because it actually is tested.)"

Answer (score 6):

The canonical example here might be in the help page for `rm`:

```
## Not run: 
## remove (almost) everything in the working environment.
## You will get no warning, so don't do this unless you are really sure.
rm(list = ls())

## End(Not run)
```

If this ran it would of course have undesired effects.

Answer (score 5):

C & p from  Chapter 5.4 (R Documentation Files) of the MUST-TO-READ [Creating R Packages: A Tutorial](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Leisch-CreatingPackages.pdf) by Friedrich Leisch:

> The examples section should contain
>   executable R code, and automatically
>   running the code  is part of checking
>   a package. There are two special
>   markup commands for the examples:
>
> **dontrun**: Everything inside \dontrun{}
>   is not executed by the tests or
>   example(). This is useful,  e.g., for
>   interactive functions, functions
>   accessing the Internet etc.. Do not
>   misuse it to make  life easier for you
>   by giving examples which cannot be
>   executed.