# gWidgetsWWW error

Tags: r, gwidgets

I am trying to run the following example from `gWidgetsWWW` vignette.

```
library(gWidgetsWWW)    
localServerOpen("/Examples/ex-simple-gui.R", package="gWidgetsWWW")
```

A new browser window opens, as it should, but I keep getting this error:

```
Error in get("..gWidgets_sessionEnv", envir = .GlobalEnv) : 
  object '..gWidgets_sessionEnv' not found
```

Any hints as to what should be done to avoid the above error?

Comment: the example in `?localServerOpen` [is encloses in "not run."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454211/what-does-not-run-mean-in-r-help-pages) There might be a reason for that (I haven't read all off the help file).

Comment: I haven't worked on this package for awhile (there is gWidgetsWWW2 on github that is better, though it needs some wrinkles taken out first) but I just noticed this issue today. I checked into the r-forge site just a few hours ago a fix for this issue.