# R ggmap (qmap) error for map type = 'watercolor'

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I was trying to use the ggmap qmap function (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ggmap/docs/qmap)

```
qmap(location = 'baylor university', zoom = 14, maptype = 'watercolor', source = 'stamen')
```

And got the following error:

> qmap(location = 'baylor university', zoom = 14, maptype =
>   'watercolor', source = 'stamen') Map from URL :
>   http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=baylor+university&zoom=14&size=%20640x640&maptype=terrain&sensor=false
>   Google Maps API Terms of Service :
>   http://developers.google.com/maps/terms Information from URL :
>   http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=baylor+university&sensor=false
>   Google Maps API Terms of Service :
>   http://developers.google.com/maps/terms Error in readPNG(destfile) :
>   file is not in PNG format

Comment: Looks like you are trying to run something from the examples found in `?ggmap`? You should note that the example-code found `?ggmap` is enclosed by `## Not run:`/`\dontrun{}`. Which, acording to [this SO-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1454340/1305688), mean that the code `shouldn't be executed in the example function'. Either because it's too time consuming or because it requires user input. I suspect the latter is the case in this example.

Answer (score 1):

qmap tries to read the files as .pngs, but stamen sends .jpg format files, which the internal function in qmap is not equipped to handle. Hopefully a new version will be out soon.

Until then, there is a manual workaround, detailed at the link below, where you essentially create your own version of the R source files used by qmap, replacing png with jpg in the code. It worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24301510/3652621