# R CMD Check fails

Tags: r

I am trying to build a package in R. I am documenting my functions (using R oxygen). As part of the documentation, I have added a few examples (using the tag @example). Now, one of my functions launches a Shiny App and I have provided an example on how to call this function in my documentation.

However, while performing a R CMD check, it reaches till this point:

```
checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... OK
```

And then does not proceed any further. I believe it has got to do with the shiny app being tested as part of R CMD checks (When I remove this particular example, it executes completely without any glitches)

What can I do to address this issue?

Comment: please paste the full output of `R CMD check`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\donttest{ YOUREXAMPLE }`

Looking around, I realize now there was a very complete synopsis of this here: [What does "not run" mean in R help pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454211/what-does-not-run-mean-in-r-help-pages/25297195#25297195)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This helped. Just one point though - I read through the responses on the link that you had posted. It was suggested that we need to use \dontrun rather than \donttest, if we intend to submit the package. Because apparently code inside \donttest is actually tested..