# What does "/dontrun" mean in R?

Tags: r

I am playing around with bsts package in R for [bayesian structural time series modeling.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bsts/index.html) I am running Example 6 on page 24 of the [manual.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bsts/bsts.pdf) This example is enclosed in "/dontrun".

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454211/what-does-not-run-mean-in-r-help-pages), "/dontrun" may include code that shouldn't be executed because it is too time-consuming or because it requires specific user input. Running the above example is neither time-consuming nor does it require specific user input, the code runs perfectly fine.

Any other suggestions? My first guess is that this part of the package may be fishy/flaky...

Code for Example 6 below

```
library(bsts)
# Load data: dataset with 456 rows (time dimension) and 11 columns (1 response, 10 predictors)
data(iclaims)
#Specify the trend and seasonality.
ss <- AddLocalLinearTrend(list(), initial.claims$iclaimsNSA)
ss <- AddSeasonal(ss, initial.claims$iclaimsNSA, nseasons = 52)
#Create object of class bsts
model <- bsts(iclaimsNSA ~ ., state.specification = ss, data =
                 initial.claims, niter = 1000)
```

Comment: Unlikely that it is fishy/flaky or whatever. Ask the author of the package?

Comment: The [time needed for checking the package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_bsts.html) is quite different for different operating systems. Maybe the code is slow on a different OS than yours?

Comment: I just tried it and it is indeed quite slow on Windows (about 24 sec on my system).

Comment: Thanks! About 22 seconds on my system (Mac OS X). If this is considered to be slow, then this may well be the answer to my question (i.e. explain the use of "dontrun").

Comment: @kanimbla, Imagine having to wait that much time each time you rebuilt the package.... (And presumably there are other examples....)