# using saveRDS in a function causes package to fail error check

Tags: r, function, package

I can't figure out why this line is causing my package to fail error check. The function works fine, without any warnings, and outputs the rds file which is readable.

But with it included, the package won't pass error check.

```
  # Save the 'full_day_crop_ts' object to the working directory
  saveRDS(full_day_crop_ts, file = file.path(data_folder, "archive_days.Rds"))
```

Here's an overview of the function page:

```
#' @name process_tag_data
#'
#' @import dplyr
#' @importFrom data.table fread
#' @importFrom data.table setDT
#' @importFrom utils read.csv
#' @importFrom stats sd
#'
#' @param Tag_ID Tag ID.
#' @param tag_deploy_UTC UTC deployment time in the correct POSIXct format: E.g. "2015-10-25 02:46:00"
#' @param tag_release_UTC UTC release time in the correct POSIXct format: E.g. "2016-10-23 23:17:35"
#' @param data_folder Data folder path. E.g. "C:/Tag data"
#' @param archive Name of the time-series depth archive
#' @param date_time_col Column number of the date time series
#' @param depth_col Column number of the depth series
#' @param time_zone Time zone of the data. E.g. ("Asia/Tokyo")
#'
#' @return A data frame of processed data.
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' ## Example archive.csv from recovered Wildlife Computers tag:
#'
#' \dontrun{
#' full_day_archive <- process_tag_data(
#'   Tag_ID = "123456",
#'   tag_deploy_UTC = "2023-10-25 02:46:00",
#'   tag_release_UTC = "2023-10-31 09:30:00",
#'   data_folder = "E:/Tag Data/123456",
#'   archive = "123456-Archive.csv",
#'   date_time_col = 1,
#'   depth_col = 2,
#'   time_zone = "Asia/Tokyo"
#' )
#' }
# Function to import tag data....
process_tag_data <- function(Tag_ID, tag_deploy_UTC, tag_release_UTC, data_folder, archive, date_time_col, depth_col, time_zone) {
  #Lots of stuff in here and 'full_day_crop_ts' gets created.

  # Save the 'full_day_crop_ts' object to the working directory
  saveRDS(full_day_crop_ts, file = file.path(data_folder, "archive_days.Rds"))

  # Return the cropped dataset
  return(full_day_crop_ts)
}
```

Calling it with:

```
# Create a metadata data frame
metadata_df <- data.frame(
  Tag_ID = c("123456", "231987"),
  tag_deploy_UTC = c("2015-10-25 02:46:00", "2016-10-08 05:25:00"),
  tag_release_UTC = c("2015-10-23 23:17:35", "2016-10-04 22:33:30"),
  data_folder = rep("E:/Ch 3 data/", 2), # Use the same data_folder for all
  date_time_col = rep(1, 2), # Use the same date_time_col for all
  depth_col = rep(2, 2), # Use the same depth_col for all
  time_zone = c("Asia/Tokyo", "Asia/Tokyo")
)

# Loop through the metadata and call process_tag_data
for (i in 1:nrow(metadata_df)) {
  archive_days <- process_tag_data(
    Tag_ID = metadata_df$Tag_ID[i],
    tag_deploy_UTC = metadata_df$tag_deploy_UTC[i],
    tag_release_UTC = metadata_df$tag_release_UTC[i],
    data_folder = paste0(metadata_df$data_folder[i],metadata_df$Tag_ID[i]),
    archive = paste0(metadata_df$Tag_ID[i], "-Archive.csv"),
    date_time_col = metadata_df$date_time_col[i],
    depth_col = metadata_df$depth_col[i],
    time_zone = metadata_df$time_zone[i]
  )
  
}
```

══ Failed tests ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
── Error ('test-process_tag_data.R:2:3'): process_tag_data() imports a tag archive ──
Error in `process_tag_data(Tag_ID = "123456", tag_deploy_UTC = "2013-10-25 02:46:00",  tag_release_UTC = "2013-10-31 09:30:00", data_folder = "E:/Tag data",  archive = "123456-Archive.csv", date_time_col = 1, depth_col = 2,  time_zone = "Asia/Tokyo")`: Data folder does not exist: E:/Tag data
Backtrace:
▆

1. └─Package::process_tag_data(...) at test-process_tag_data.R:2:3

[ FAIL 1 | WARN 0 | SKIP 0 | PASS 0 ]
Error: Test failures
Execution halted

1 error ✖ | 0 warnings ✔ | 2 notes ✖
Error: R CMD check found ERRORs
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.

Comment: Are you trying to publish this package to CRAN? It's not a good idea to hard code paths like `E:\` which are windows specific paths and not necessarily available on every computer. If this is coming from an example in the help page, you can make the example as [do not run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454211/what-does-not-run-mean-in-r-help-pages) so it doesn't get executed when checking the package.

Comment: directory paths were just placeholders but got me thinking and i realised the error is with the example data not the actual functioning code. 
The directory E:/Tag data didn't exist and was causing the error, even though it's inside \dontrun{#' full_day_archive <- process_tag_data( ... )
#' }

Answer (score 0):

even though it's within the don't run the directory for the example needed to be real.
After creating "E:/Tag data" the check ran without any issues.